# Typescript: Is it possible to key off of type parameters for function overloads? (Example in post)

Tags: typescript

I know typescript will observe input parameters for a function to determine which overload to use however is it possible for typescript to also consider type parameters? In my example I'd like one overload to be chosen over another if the type parameters match that overload. Example below:

1. Define model required for overloads

```js
export interface Address<AddressXp = any> {
    CompanyName?: string;
    FirstName?: string;
    LastName?: string;
    Street1: string;
    Street2?: string;
    City: string;
    State: string;
    Zip: string;
    Country: string;
    Phone?: string;
    xp?: AddressXp;
}
```

2. Define Overloads

```js
function GetAddress<IAddress extends Address>(): IAddress
function GetAddress<AddressXp = any>(): Address<AddressXp> {
    return {} as any;
}
```

3. Test overloads

Scenario 1.

```
var address1 = GetAddress(); // address1.xp is type any (as expected), hit first overload
```

Scenario 2.

```js
interface MyAddressXp {
    Street3: string;
}

interface MyAddress extends Address<MyAddressXp> {}
var address2 = GetAddress<MyAddress>(); // address2.xp.Street3 is typed (as expected), hit first overload
```

Scenario 3

```js
interface MyOtherAddressXp {
    Street4: string;
}
var address3 = GetAddress<MyOtherAddressXp>();
```

Here we run into issues. I would expect address3.xp.Street4 to be typed however I get a type error:

```
/*
    Error for address3:
    Type '{ Street4: string; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Address<any>'.
    Type '{ Street4: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Address<any>':
    Street1, City, State, Zip, Country ts(2344)
*/
```

It seems its not hitting the second overload. In fact when i completely remove the first overload there are no typed errors but then of course it is not typed correctly for the second scenario

Comment: I don't know if something is missing but your model has `Street1`, `Street2`, and `Street3` but you've tried to pass `Street4`, so it doesn't match any of your overloads.

Comment: I think it should match my second overload shouldnt it? Street4 is the type parameter im passing in. It has a default type of any but that shouldnt really matter for this case. When I remove the first overload it works but then of course address2 isnt typed correctly

Comment: I updated the example so it's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function itself is not part of the overload specification. In your example you use

`function GetAddress<AddressXp = any>(): Address<AddressXp>` but those type constraints are ignored when calling the function. So your issue is that you really only have 1 "overload"

You can update the code for example like:

```
function GetAddress<IAddress extends Address>(): IAddress
function GetAddress<AddressXp = any>(): Address<AddressXp>
function GetAddress(): any {
    return {} as any;
}
```

Guidance from the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function pickCard(x: {suit: string; card: number; }[]): number;
function pickCard(x: number): {suit: string; card: number; };
function pickCard(x): any {
    // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
    // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
    if (typeof x == "object") {
        let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
        return pickedCard;
    }
    // Otherwise just let them pick the card
    else if (typeof x == "number") {
        let pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13);
        return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 };
    }
}
```

> In order for the compiler to pick the correct type check, it follows a similar process to the underlying JavaScript. It looks at the
>   overload list and, proceeding with the first overload, attempts to
>   call the function with the provided parameters. If it finds a match,
>   it picks this overload as the correct overload. For this reason, it’s
>   customary to order overloads from most specific to least specific.
>
> Note that the function `pickCard(x): any` piece is not part of the
>   overload list, so it only has two overloads: one that takes an object
>   and one that takes a number. Calling `pickCard` with any other parameter
>   types would cause an error.